# CamelCase only for some part of the line using shell tool

Tags: shell, awk, sed

my goal is to have a one liner to generate a list of variables composed from the name of the variable and its value. The **value** must be kept "as-is" while the **name** of the variable must be CamelCase, when removing leading slash "/" or dot "." or dash "-"

Sample of input:

```
auto-scaling/v2/HorizontalPodAutoscaler
v1/Service
apiextensions.k8s.io/v1/CustomResourceDefinition
```

Expected output:

```
AutoScalingV2HorizontalPodAutoscaler.$ : "auto-scaling/v2/HorizontalPodAutoscaler"
V1Service.$ : "v1/Service"
ApiextensionsK8sIoV1CustomResourceDefinition.$ : "apiextensions.k8s.io/v1/CustomResourceDefinition"
```

I found some clue in stackoverflow to transform a full string in CamelCase using awk or sed but those are for the full *line* while I would only what the part before the .$" (or the ":" as I could add after the ".$ " part)

```
echo "apiextensions.k8s.io/v1/CustomResourceDefinition" | sed -r 's/(^|[-_/\.]+)([0-9a-z])/\U\2/g'
ApiextensionsK8sIoV1/CustomResourceDefinition

echo "apiextensions.k8s.io/v1/CustomResourceDefinition" | awk 'BEGIN{FS="";RS="[-./]";ORS=""} {$0=toupper(substr($0,1,1)) substr($0,2)} 1'
ApiextensionsK8sIoV1CustomResourceDefinition
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below awk to achieve your purpose:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="";RS="[-./]";ORS=""} {$0=toupper(substr($0,1,1)) substr($0,2)} 1'
```

**Explanation of the above command:**

- **`BEGIN{FS="";RS="[-./]";ORS=""}`** - Set the separators.

  - **`FS=""`** - [Field Separator (FS)](https://learnbyexample.github.io/learn_gnuawk/Exercise_solutions.html?highlight=field#field-separators) is set to make each character behave like a separate field.
  - **`RS="[-./]"`** - [Record Separator (RS)](https://learnbyexample.github.io/learn_gnuawk/record-separators.html#record-separators) is set to a regex which  matches `[-./]` and separates according to it. You can add or remove them based on your specific purpose.
  - **`ORS=""`** -  [Output Record Separator (ORS)](https://learnbyexample.github.io/learn_gnuawk/record-separators.html#output-record-separator) is set to avoid printing new lines.
- **`{toupper(substr($0,1,1))`** - It will take the first character of record and converts it to uppercase and prepend it to the output.
- **`substr($0,2)`** - Appends the rest of input to the output record.
- **`1`** - shorthand to `{print}` current record.

***[CODE DEMO](https://replit.com/@msankrit/MeagerUnknownStruct#main.sh)***

Comment: Perfect, I was able to adapt the code demo to fit my needs by using a script. Thanks

Comment: For the benefit of anyone coming across this in future you should mention that requires GNU awk for a) multi-char RS, and b) splitting using a null FS (though you aren't actually doing anything that needs that), it won't work with a POSIX awk because in POSIX if more than 1 char is provided for RS every char after the first gets cut off, and splitting with a null FS is undefined behavior so YMMV with what that does. It also won't produce the expected output shown in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -F '[-/.]' -v OFS='.$ : "' -v ORS='"\n' '{
    name = ""
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        name = name toupper(substr($i,1,1)) substr($i,2)
    }
    print name, $0
}' file
AutoScalingV2HorizontalPodAutoscaler.$ : "auto-scaling/v2/HorizontalPodAutoscaler"
V1Service.$ : "v1/Service"
ApiextensionsK8sIoV1CustomResourceDefinition.$ : "apiextensions.k8s.io/v1/CustomResourceDefinition"
```

Answer (score -1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed -E 'h;s/\b./\U&/g;s/[[:punct:]]//g;G;s/\n(.*)/.$ : "\1"/' file
```

Make a copy.

CamelCase the variable.

Append the copy.

Produce the desired output.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton. Hopefully removed the right sequences.